# How to avoid duplicate users when I am using get_users?

Tags: array, users

I using get_users to get users from my database.

I am using this code:

```
$args = array (
        'role'           => 'Colaborador',
        'role__not_in' =>[ 'subscriber', 'Administrator'],
        'orderby' => 'rand'


    );


$users = get_users($args );
```

But in the output when use the foreach  to print the data I need  I found that are some user that are duplicate, appearing twice in the array.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's arguments issue.

I recommend not to use `role` & `role__not_in` together rather either use only `role` OR use `role__in` & `role__not_in` combination. Also check your `role` param spelling. ([see more on role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities))

2ndly `orderby` param `rand` is not valid according to codex ([see here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)) so use proper param.

Comment: I remove role__not_in  and check the role param spelling.     But stil I get duplicate users in the query

Comment: Ok, don't worry; try this `$args = array('role'=>'contributor', 'orderby'=>'login');` and let me if not worked.